# Connection string keyword "...." is not supported

Tags: asp.net, database, connection-string

I'm trying to update database after create migration. I am not really experienced with this.when I use command: "dotnet ef database update",it always show: "Connection string keyword 'server' is not supported". Here is my connection string:

```
`"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=test1;Uid=root;Pwd=;",
    "ProviderName": "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
  }
`
```

I already change the connection string to

```
Data Source=localhost:3306;Database=test1;Uid=root;Pwd=;
```

but after change to this connection string, it always appear error "Connection string keyword 'database' is not supported".
I also change keyword "Database" to "Initial Catalog" but it also appear errors "Connection string keyword 'Initial Catalog' is not supported"
Can you help me due with this problem

Comment: How did you set up Entity Framework in the DI configuration? Is it maybe using the wrong provider?